# T-SQL: How to break a column with concatenated string into multiple rows?

Tags: sql-server, r

I'm working with a dataset where most columns are normal, but one has one or more concatenated values jammed into a single string, using a '|' as a delimiter between values. I need to reshape it so that there's one row per existing row, per concatenated value. There are 60 potential values--that I know of-- in the concatenated string, and most rows have between 0 and 10 values smashed into the string. It's also going to be necessary to repeat this process over the next few months, and it's possible the list will change/ add new members.

I'm going to have to do this on an unknown number of future tables--at least 4 more--so if there's an approach I can easily repurpose it will be MUCH better. Also, I'm using t-SQL, but l could probably bring in R or something if that would help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table containing the 60 possible values, you could join to it with tsql something like this:

select table1.id, potentialvalues.value
from table1 
inner join potentialvalues
on charindex('|'+potentialvalues.value+'|', '|'+table1.concatField+'|')>0

Note:  Added the pipes to beginning and end of the concatfield so that it can match the first and last values in the field.  So, if your concatfield is something like '1|2|10' on a record it would be able to match '|1|', '|2|' and '|10|'.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I'll try it on Tuesday and report back.

Comment: I think a variation on this will work: a left join on potentialvalues.value= SUBSTRING(table.concatstring, CHARINDEX(value,concatstring), LEN(value)). A bonus is that it cleaned out the pipes. Thanks for getting me in the right track!

Answer (score 0):

In R, you could use dplyr and tidyr functions to expand your rows by separating each combined string at the pipe symbol. This has the advantage that it can be applied to your table without knowing what the piped combinations are in advance.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df, string, sep = "[|]") %>% 
  mutate(string = trimws(string))
```

The trimws function from base R is used to remove any extra whitespace that may be between your piped string components. Toy test data and results shown below.

**Test data**

```
df = data.frame(key = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                string = c("Simple", "Piped 1 | Piped 2", "Simple 2", "Piped A1 | Piped A2 | Piped A3"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> df
  key                         string
1   A                         Simple
2   B              Piped 1 | Piped 2
3   C                       Simple 2
4   D Piped A1 | Piped A2 | Piped A3
```

**Result**

```
  key   string
1   A   Simple
2   B  Piped 1
3   B  Piped 2
4   C Simple 2
5   D Piped A1
6   D Piped A2
7   D Piped A3
```